# Reproducing Python script in R via "reticulate"

Tags: python, r

I am trying to recreate a working python script using RStudio's `reticulate` package for python. The working script is an adaption of dlib's [face detection script](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html). I have it almost working, I think, but I do not know how to enumerate along an object. In the original script, it reads:

```
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("path/to/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

image = cv2.imread("path/to/defiant2.jpg")
print(image.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

rects = detector(gray, 1)

for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

    bb = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)


rect = shape[1]
for rect in shape:
    print("{} {}".format(*rect))
print("{} {} {} {}".format(*bb))
```

When I try and recreate this in R to the best of my ability, I hit a roadblock when it is supposed to enumerate along the dlib detector object. Specifically, I get the following error:

```
library(reticulate)

cv2 <- import('cv2', convert = FALSE)
dlib <- import('dlib', convert = FALSE)
face_utils <- import('imutils.face_utils')
imutils <- import('imutils')
np <- import('numpy')
main <- import_main()
py <- import_builtins()

shape_predictor = 'shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'
img = 'defiant2.jpg'

detector = dlib$get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib$shape_predictor(shape_predictor)

image = cv2$imread(img)
gray = cv2$cvtColor(image, cv2$COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

rects = detector$run(gray)

py$enumerate(rects)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Any help in transferring the code to R would be greatly appreciated. If it helps, I have uploaded the full script files, as well as a test image and the shape predictor landmarks file to [Github](https://github.com/d-bohn/face_detect_example).

Comment: Can you run your own python script in R with reticulate?

Comment: yes, reticulate has a function 'source_python' that runs a python script and loads its outputs into R